# Is there a way to force Tor reconnect immediately after network down?

Tags: configuration

When I turn off my connection and connect again, Tor takes between 10 and 30 seconds to reconnect.

Is there a way to force Tor reconnect immediately after network goes back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no, and there is a good reason for it: 10 to 30 seconds are the default *timeouts*, so it will **not** hang unreconnected when your connection is back. Also - as practice shows us - this is a usual timing for a DHCP renewal from your upstream ISP, so these values are more than sane. Even if you could possibly force it to reconnect immediately - check the bootstapping timings in your log - you will not pop up connected to the Tor network instantly, so there's no goal in this